# Does SSL inspection break applications utilizing certificate pinning?

Tags: tls, certificates, tls-intercept, certificate-pinning

A number of popular mobile apps utilize certificate pinning, such as Facebook. Does this mean that these applications cease to function completely on corporate and academic networks that utilize SSL inspection, unless the administrator specifically exempts them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean that these applications cease to function completely on
>   corporate and academic networks that utilize SSL inspection, unless
>   the administrator specifically exempts them

Yes,You are right the apps that use certificate pinning wont work in an MITM situation.They didnt work when i tried so i think its a fair assumption to make that they wont work in corporate and academic networks that utilize SSL inspection
**unless the administrator specifically exempts that traffic and doesnt try to MITM it**.

Comment: which is, in many cases, the thing which one wants to archieve by pinning the cert